# How to check to see if a function in R is a constant function?

Tags: r, function, constants

An R function is passed to me, which is defined on some interval of the Real Line and returns a numeric value.
Is there a way to check to see if the function is constant?

Example functions:

```
f1<-function(x) {11}
f2<-function(x) {x+2}
f3<-function(x) {1+1}
f4<-function(x) {return(3)}
```

I am looking for a test that will say that f1,f3,f4 are constant functions but f2 isn't. Any Ideas?

**Edit:**

Frank's and Gregor's (**edit:** and Michael Lawrence's second solution)solutions below all work for all the 4 test cases given above (Marat's and Michael's don't work on all 4 cases). So there is already solutions. But extra bonus points if you can find a solution which also gives the right answer for the following 3 test functions:

```
f5 <- function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 1)
f6 <- function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 0)
f7 <- function(x) {x - x}
```

Comment: The best you can do is try a bunch of values. Good luck catching my function `f3 = function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do programmatically for arbitrary functions. But if you can tell the context, maybe someone would be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: Yes exactly Gregor, I would like to be able to catch such function.
That's why I was hoping to have a programmtic solution that exactly isn't testing a bunch of values. Because R knows the function the info is theoretically there ...

Comment: But my function is a constant function if your domain is 0 to 5. For this to be a reasonable problem to solve, I think you need to be able to make stronger assumptions. How are these functions being created? Do you have a fixed domain? How complex are the functions, might they call other functions? I could also write a very obtuse function that looks very complicated but **is** always constant.

Comment: Yes, you're right Gregor.

Comment: If you want to test whether the code uses `x` as a number, just pass a nonnumber and enjoy the error: `f1("a"); f2("a")`. This won't capture cases where constancy is mathematical, not programmatic, as Gregor said, like `f3 <- function(x){x-x}`. For that, Mathematica maybe? I hear it can simplify formulas...

Comment: That's also a really good solution Frank :)

Comment: @Frank, I think your solution is the best. If you want to write it up, I will accept it. The problem with Marat's solution (appart from convoluted functions of course) is that it doesn't work with the function
f5<-function(x){return(3)}
.

Comment: I don't know R, but is it possible to override `ifelse` to e.g. return a random number? So that `function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 0)` isn't necessarily constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function tests if the argument of `f` is used as a number:

```
is_using_argasnumber <- function(f) 
  grepl("non-numeric argument",try(f("Hello World!"),silent=TRUE))
```

---

**Examples:**

```
is_using_argasnumber(function(x)1+1)        # FALSE
is_using_argasnumber(function(x)"guffaw")   # FALSE
is_using_argasnumber(function(x)sqrt(x+2))  # TRUE
```

If you need to test whether a mathematical function is constant, you'll need special tools that understand and can simplify formulas.

---

**Generality.**

- It doesn't make sense on functions with multiple arguments.
- If using a different localization of R, ...

  - I'd suggest replacing or adding to the regex, e.g., with `"(non-numeric argument)|(argument non numérique)"`. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, R does not use or expose "error codes" that would allow for language-invariant interpretation a `try` result.
  - An alternative proposed by the OP would be simply checking whether there was *any* error, but I think that would create too many false positives if the functions being tested had any chance of bugginess:

.

```
is_breaking_withargascharacter <- function(f)
  inherits(try(f("Hello World!"),silent=TRUE),'try-error')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's good but it only works if your system language is english ;)

Comment: For example I get:
try(f2("Hello World!"))
Error in x + 2 : argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire

Comment: It would be better if the solution were modified to simply catch an error.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse Yes, I agree. I'm not used to error-catching and so am looking into how to modify it now. However, it is sort of nice to know that we are catching the right error... like with an error code, assuming R has those.

Comment: So something like
                 
is_using_argasnumber <- function(f) 
     tryCatch({f("a")
               FALSE},error =function(e) TRUE)

             
seems to the the trick. But you are right. It would be good to be able to catch the exact error and not just any error...

Comment: Hahaha :) I guess to make it really complicated one could check if there is an error with a number as well, if there is no error with a number then we could assume the function is not buggy if there is an error with a number then throw an error. But then the question becomes which number to use ... 0 wouldn't work with log, 1 wouldn't work arctan ...

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse Yeah, best to just define and understand the functions carefully from the start :)

Answer (score 11):

Try `functionBody`:

```
> is.numeric(functionBody(f1)[[2]])
[1] TRUE

> is.numeric(functionBody(f2)[[2]])
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks!! 
It's not fool proof, for example
f4 = function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 0)
comes up as not constant even though it is. But it is close enough.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse - because that is technically a function call, and not a constant.  It depends on another variable :)

Comment: A more serious problem with this method is that the following function is given as not constant:
f5<-function(x){return(3)}

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse, Try `f3 <- function() { 1+1 }`. Simplest I think ;)

Comment: I guess you need to use symbolic algebra for more complicated cases. Maybe, try `Ryacas`?

Comment: You can probably add `eval` to Marat's answer to make sure you get evaluation to happen, as 1+1 is also a function call.  Like `is.numeric(eval(functionBody(f3)[[2]]))`

Comment: @RichardScriven, yes but it doesn't depend on any other variable. It's a constant function, right?

Comment: @B.Shankar `'+'(3, 4)  [1] 7` It is a function. It has two dependencies. (use backticks btw). `return(3)` is also a function. Marat's solution works.

Comment: @RichardScriven True but it gives an error (instead of False) if the function actually depends on a variable (for example f2 in the question).

Comment: As soon as there is a function call, all bets are off. An easy to fix issue with this answer is that it needs to be robust to not having a `{`. And a better check is `!is.language()` rather than `is.numeric()`.

Comment: @MichaelLawrence That's not a fix, though...gotta get unreasonably clever in navigating the function body, I guess. `maratest <- function(f) !is.language(functionBody(f)[[2]]); maratest(function(x)1) # error, subscript out of bounds`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that it was a fix. Navigating the structure of the language is easy. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 5):

These code-based tests are clever and fun to see, but so far I think the "try a bunch of numbers" approach may be a more powerful test, depending on the type of functions you might get and whether you care more about Type I or Type II errors in your identification.

In your question, you say

> which is defined on some interval of the Real Line

So let's assume we know the domain of interest. Sample some number of points on that domain, and test your function.

```
n = 1e5
test = runif(n, min = 0, max = 5)
results = f(test) # sapply(test, f) if f isn't vectorized

# test for constancy
all(results == results[1]) # or all(diff(results) == 0) or however else
```

Any function that is truly a constant function will pass this test just fine, no matter how pathological---this will not be true for any of the other methods suggested so far. However, it is quite easy to fool the test with the example I left in the comments (or anything of this sort)

```
f3 = function(x) ifelse(x == 5.46512616432116, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I'm still not sure if the OP was looking for the function-properties or math-properties test, but I like this solution to the latter, at least in the form of "How can I test if my real-valued function from a compact subset of the reals is constant?"

Comment: And, if the functions aren't somehow "randomly" generated, it would be easy to also check "special" values, 0 if it's included in the domain, checking perhaps the values in `pretty(mydomain)`.

Answer (score 5):

This handles cases like explicit `return`, missing `{` and even empty `{ }`:

```
evaluatesToConstant <- function(b) {
    if (is(b, "{")) {
        if (length(b) > 2L)
            return(FALSE)
        if (length(b) == 1L)
            last <- NULL
        else last <- b[[2L]]
    } else {
        last <- b
    }
    if (is.call(last) && last[[1L]] == quote(return)) {
        last <- last[[2L]]
    }
    !is.language(last)
}
evaluatesToConstant(functionBody(fun))
```

Here is another approach that is pretty smart, but it can be tricked. It will assume that any primitive function will return the same value, given constant arguments. It also allows symbols, as long as the symbols are defined within the function. But since symbols can be referenced before being defined, or defined but in a nested scope, that heuristic is not safe. Anyway, here it is:

```
evaluatesToConstant <- function(expr, allowDefinitions=FALSE) {
    vars <- all.vars(expr)
    calls <- setdiff(all.names(expr), vars)
    funs <- mget(calls, parent.frame(), mode="function", inherits=TRUE)
    defined <- if (allowDefinitions)
                   rapply(as.list(expr),
                          function(x) as.character(substitute(x)[[2L]]), "<-",
                          how="unlist")
    length(setdiff(vars, defined)) == 0L &&
        all(vapply(funs, is.primitive, logical(1L)))
}
```

Should be `TRUE`:

```
evaluatesToConstant(functionBody(function(x) { foo <- 1 + 1; foo }), TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried your function, but it fails for f2 in the question. It gives true while it should be false.........
> evaluatesToConstant(f2)
[1] TRUE
> f2
function(x) {x+2}

Comment: sorry. my bad, I didn't realize I should do evaluatesToConstant(functionBody(fun))
and not simply evaluatesToConstant.

Comment: Yea, because to support things like `+`, one would need to whitelist function calls that always return the same result given constant arguments. I guess that might be true of any primitive. I will add a different approach to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you pretend that the function is its "mathworld" counterpart, the answer to the question is recursively undecidable.